# Duda sobre encapsulacion y objetos en POO

Tags: java, poo

Una de las principales características de la programación orientada a objetos es la encapsulación, me pregunto ¿se deben poner todas las propiedades en private? ¿incluso los objetos? ¿hay algun caso en el que se pueda prescindir de esto o es una regla como tal en POO?

Ejemplo

```
package PureShit;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class clase2 {
private File f;



public clase2(String ruta) {
    f = new File(ruta);
}



public File getF() {
    return f;
}



public void setF(File f) {
    this.f = f;
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro del tema de POO, debemos distinguir lo siguiente:

**ENCAPSULAMIENTO**

1. **Public** => Todos los métodos y propiedades que sean declarados de este modo son accesibles desde cualquier punto, es decir dentro y fuera de la propia clase que los define
2. **Private** => Todos los elementos que son declarados de este modo son únicamente accesibles dentro del ambito de la clase que los delcaró
3. **Protected** => Todos los elementos que son declarados de este modo, son accesibles dentro de la clase que los declaró así como únicamente por aquellas clases que heredan de la que los contiene

El tema de aplicar el encapsulamiento debe ir precedido de comprender el nivel de acceso que debe tener cada método y/o propiedad que necesites declarar

**EJEMPLO CON PROTECTED**

En este fragmento de código le estoy indicando que tanto la propiedad que almacenará la conexión, como el método que me va a permitir conectarme al gestor de la base de datos, entonces toda clase que no herede de `Server` no podrá acceder a lo anteriormente mencionado

```
public class Server
{
    protected String conexion;

    protected Server(String server)
    {
        server = server;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    }
}
```

**EJEMPLO CON PUBLIC**

Dentro del siguiente fragmento de código, tanto la propiedad de conexión, como el mismo método de conexión son accesibles desde cualquier punto; lo cual por ejemplo supone un problema por que no todas las clases de tu software la van a ocupar

```
public class Server
{
    public String conexion;

    public Server(String server)
    {
        server = server;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Es lo que buscaba, te dejo la respuesta como valida.

Answer (score 1):

Todo depende de la arquitectura de tu proyecto y la forma en que la gente utilizará tu código. La regla de oro es poner todo en *private* hasta que tú u otra parte necesite acceso a dicha propiedad. Una vez necesitado el acceso debes plantearte la integridad de la propiedad, si la propiedad tiene como *dominio* todos los objetos del mismo tipo de dato, entonces estableces la propiedad como *public*. Ahora si el dominio es restringido (los valores que puede tomar) deberás validar que la propiedad sea válida en todo momento, en este caso deberás crear *setters*. Existen casos en que se desea acceder a la propiedad y realizar cambios que no sean reflejados directamente, en este caso se suele crear un *getter* que devuelva una *copia* de la propiedad de lo contrario se suele crear un *getter* que simplemente devuelva la propiedad (los cambios serán directamente reflejados).

Comment: Perfecto!, la verdad es que me hago un lio de si en mi proyecto debo de usar private,protected o public, ya que usando el modificador public te ahorras los setter y getters pero segun la teoria eso no se debe usar en POO

Comment: ¿Pero si no se debe usar por qué existe?

Comment: @FrEqDe si se creó se asume que al menos la clase donde se declaró hace uso de la propiedad. Cuando escribí "hasta que tú la necesites" me refiero a que necesite el acceso desde otra clase.